# Passing two values to php file using jquery.load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have a jquery.load function passing one varaible to a php script. Please see code below. I am wanting to pass a second varaible to the php script at the same time called choiceparent how would i do this?

Cheers

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#product").change(function() {
        $("#version").load("getter.php?choiceproduct=" + encodeURIComponent($("#product").val()));

        });

        });
```

Comment: after val(), use this +"variablename=" + variablevalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use & to pass more parameters(shown below), dnt forget to add choiceparent value in code

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#product").change(function() {
                $("#version").load("getter.php?choiceproduct=" + encodeURIComponent($("#product").val())+"&choiceparent="+encodeURIComponent(PUT CHOICEPARENT VALUE HERE));

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#version").load("getter.php?choiceproduct=" + encodeURIComponent($("#product").val()) + "&choiceparent=SOMEVALUE");
```

You can add as many asw you want, just remember to use + "&VARIABLE=VALUE" :)